# How long can a given volume of air in an airtight chamber remain breathable?

Tags: physics, hard-science

If we have a known volume of air in an airtight chamber (basically, in a spaceship) of atmospheric composition and pressure, and we know the number of people in the chamber, how long does the air remain breathable?

Basically, given a volume V of air at 1 atm and the standard composition (78% Nitrogen, 21% Oxygen, with the remaining 1% composed of carbon dioxide, argon, etc.), how long can X people remain alive (or rather, conscious) in that chamber, assuming there is no exchange of matter between the inside of the chamber and its surroundings (ie space)?

Other problems regarding the survival of the crew, such as food, water, waste disposal, heat, etc. are out of scope. I only want to know about breathable air and how long it lasts.

Edits:

- The oxygen goes down mostly by human consumption. There are no fires, no chemical reactions taking place etc. The mostly is there because there may or may not be gunshots taking place in this chamber based on its purpose. I hope that will not complicate stuff too much, but that is going to be rare as it is.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120864/discussion-on-question-by-ribhu-hooja-how-long-can-a-given-volume-of-air-in-an-a).

Answer (score 9):

Since I feel like I should turn my comment into an answer:

I am basically directly copying the formula from [this site](http://www-das.uwyo.edu/%7Egeerts/cwx/notes/chap01/ox_exer.html):

> Where:
>
> - t = time lapsed from initial time to time of loss of consciousness (s)
> - Vr = volume of enclosure (m<sup>3</sup>)
> - Vp = volume of a person (about 0.1 m<sup>3</sup>)
> - Li = initial oxygen concentration (21% or 0.21)
> - Lf = final oxygen concentration (12% or 0.12)
> - n = number of people in enclosure
> - C = per capita rate of oxygen consumption (3.33 10-6 m<sup>3</sup> s-1)

> Therefore:
>
> - t = {Vr - nVp}{Li - Lf} / nC

If you have Volume in m<sup>3</sup>, and you want a simple rough estimate of passing out around 15% oxygen concentration, then you could just do:

> Number of Hours = (Volume/Number of People - 0.1) * 5

Edit: Corrected my own bad math, and added a couple more details.

Comment: You realize that you'll be poisoned by the carbon dioxide concentration long before you run out of oxygen, right?

Comment: My rough math includes unconsciousness at around 15% Oxygen concentration or 6% CO2 concentration.  According to [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5380556/), convulsions, coma, and death start at 10%.  Between 5% and 10%, you can expect "depression of the respiration and the circulation" which probably helps with the passing out, but that will only be in effect for the last few hours of consciousness anyway.  I'm not saying you won't be poisoned, but it's a race between the poison and the oxygen to knock you out.

Comment: "C = per capita rate of oxygen consumption (3.33 10-6 m3 s-1)" What does this even mean? Everything else in the equation is just filler. This is a fancy term for 'unknown, unknowable but let's make a guess'. It assumes oxygen is being converted from one form to another, but fails to indicate the resultant chemistry, nor of all the competing factors for oxygen. If oxygen levels drop from 21% to 12%, it has to go somewhere. Oxygen does not become some other element.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond The oxygen becomes CO2 (and to a lesser extent water) when respired.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond [per capita](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/per_capita), though the meaning should be clear from the denominator. Taking the standard oxygen consumption value defined in a [MET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metabolic_equivalent_of_task) as 3.5ml/kg/min for a resting adult, and given an average adult mass of 60kg you'll get a consumption rate of $3.5\times 10^{-6}m^3/s$ which is pretty close to the given but unsourced value.

Comment: @SirTain anyway, you can certainly add a mass parameter to your equation, and even add per-person oxygen demands based on the values give in the MET link above. Seems like a nice way to take care of the complaints in the comments below the OP, too.

Comment: @Mike Scott Precisely my point. For a hard science answer, 'C' is just a fancy term for 'then magic happens'. The Mike Sefras answer at least describes where the oxygen goes, and why. It links it to specific chemical reactions, not some nebulous 'rate of oxygen consumption'. Oxygen is NOT destroyed, It is still present, just in some other form. It still has to be accounted for. On Earth, a sealed self-contained system, the total oxygen levels is never 'replenished' from 'outside sources', and the timeline is indefinite.

Answer (score 3):

### It depends on the people and their metabolic rate, and whether you can scrounge up something alkaline.

People trapped in a cave may not be keeping up with breakfast, but they are still burning calories internally.  Figure out the amount of "food Calories" (kcal) all the people together *would* need to eat to stay at their present weight.  So if you have a girl who eats 1200 kcal a day and a big man who eats 2800 kcal a day, start with 4000 kcal.  If need be you can try to [estimate this](https://healthjade.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/basal-metabolic-rate-with-age-and-sex.jpg) from a chart relating BMI, sex, and age.

Convert the calories to grams of fat (approximately -CH2-) using 9 kcal = 1 gram, or carbohydrate (-CH2O-) using 4 kcal = 1 gram.  For -CH2- 14 grams = 1 mol and for -CH2O- 30 grams = 1 mol.  *And* 1 mol -CH2- + 1.5 mol O2 = CO2 + H2O while 1 mol -CH2O- + 1 mol O2 = CO2 + H2O.  Putting all that together, (9 kcal/g)(14 g/mol)(1 mol -CH2- / 1.5 mol O2) = 84 kcal -CH2- / mol O2 and (4 kcal/g)(30 g/mol)(1 mol -CH2O- / mol O2) = 120 kcal -CH2O- / mol O2.

Now a mole of O2 or CO2 takes up 22 liters of space in a cold cave and 24 liters in a warm one.  For this space ship I think we can assume a 25 C room temperature, so 24.45 L/mol.  Even supposing it cooled down to the freezing point of the water for the radiation shield, that would only decrease the pressure; the amount of air remains the same.  Being cold has a much larger effect by [raising the energy usage 30% for "mild cold"](https://www.theatlantic.com/health/archive/2014/02/how-being-cold-burns-calories/283810/) and up to 5 times more for Antarctic explorer grade cold.  But at normal temperatures, for every 84 calories you burn, you're using up 24 liters of oxygen and creating a precisely equal volume of carbon dioxide.  The amount of "air" used will be a little less than five times that, so we can say 1.4 liters per kcal = **1.4 cubic meters per 1000 "Calories" burned**.  Unless you still have protein or carbohydrate you're digesting, or for a few hours after that liver glycogen, in which case you're using about 50% more.

You can use up about 2/3 of the oxygen before people die - the Death Zone of Everest is 356 millibars of pressure.  The *big* variable is whether you can do anything about the CO2.  With CO2, even 1% will be annoying, and 5% (which means 25% of the total air has been used) is a big problem.  But almost any aqueous solution of a strongly alkaline substance will absorb CO2, because carbon dioxide reacts with water to form carbonic acid, and if you can neutralize the acid to bicarbonate or carbonate that reaction just keeps going and going.

Notice that "conserving energy" to conserve oxygen is rather overrated.  I mean, picture you're gasping for breath with a stair-climbing machine and it tells you that you have managed to burn 16 calories ... go out and reward yourself with a green bean.  And the guilty feeling you used up 11 soda bottles' worth of air.

Comment: A really, really good description worthy of the hard science tag. It directly relates at the chemistry level where the oxygen atoms go, and relates it to calories and energy. The oxygen atoms do not just disappear, they re-form into CO2., and with scrubbers, into carbonic acid and other byproducts. If there is a process that retrieves the oxygen locked up in carbonic acid, like photosynthesis, life can be preserved indefinitely. Oxygen atoms are never destroyed. Oxygen does not have to be 'replenished', it just needs to be 'reconstituted'.